# Ionic Geolocation takes too much time to get position

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm testing an Ionic 3.4 app, which used to work perfectly in browser. After installing some Cordova plugins (some may still be missing), I installed the latest Android SDK and the 4.0 (which is the SDK level I'm aiming for).

Made a JS google maps page which loads some components from my DB, that works really fine in the browser. But... in the mobile phone (Xiaomi mi5s, Android 6.0.1) it needs the GPS to work, and it takes like 2-3 minutes to load the current position. No exaggeration: 2-3 mins.

The problem seems to be in this line:

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
```

After that time, it passes through this line and points to my exact location. That works fine, but it shouldn't take so much time.

This is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "MyApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Ionic Framework",
    "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "^3.6.0",
        "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^3.5.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
        "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
        "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
        "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
        "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "~1.4.0",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.1",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
        "image-manipulation": "0.0.4",
        "ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
        "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "parse": "^1.9.2",
        "rxjs": "5.1.1",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.3.1",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.4.0",
        "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.3.1",
        "typescript": "~2.2.1"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
            "cordova-plugin-console": {},
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {
                "API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "AIzaSyDFX_9vIksX3JMDVjDIRa5bxoioWCW_q4g",
                "API_KEY_FOR_IOS": "AIzaSyDFX_9vIksX3JMDVjDIRa5bxoioWCW_q4g"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
}
```

What's wrong here?

Thank you!

EDIT: Ok, the snippet works good in a Samsung S5, but it won't work in my Xiaomi mi5s... any idea?

Comment: some times being inside a building will delay things when getting the current location

Comment: Yes, but with other apps, it works neat. Something's wrong with Ionic native Geolocation, I think.

Comment: i am using the same plugin, same version and it takes 2 seconds to find my current location, i have multiple test devices. Its not the plugin to blame

Comment: also try to set enableHighAccuracy : false

Comment: It works in other devices, but not in my Xiaomi mi5s... what's wrong here?

Comment: have u checked if both of the devices have the same gps location settings?

Comment: They have. I've checked the GPS permission for geolocation in MIUI, and it's enabled. I also changed some other security settings as battery optimization off, so it uses all the power it can. It still struggles to work.

It seems to be a problem of MIUI with the Android geolocation service... it also fails in navigators as I've seen, but not in Google Maps. What may be wrong? Should I report this bug?

Comment: when u first try to get the location, android asks you for permission, correct?

Comment: @Akis yes, it does. But after that, it takes too much to get my location... if it does. Sometimes it doesn't, and once, it got it quite quick (well, 15 s, which still isn't quick, but normally it takes 2-3 min)

Comment: in general the plugin works for Xiaomi, but i dont know if it is a specific device issue or it could be anything else. I wish i could help more

Comment: I also have this problem with Xiaomi Redmi 4

Comment: yes i am also facing same problem. in android getcurrentlocation take exact 5 seconds and in ios take 1 to 2 seconds. is there any solution?